# What is the difference between logging.info and logging.getLogger().info?

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

If `logging.info()` is enough for logging, why we have to instantiate a logger with `getLogger()` method?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Calling `getLogger()` without a name [returns the root logger](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#logging.getLogger):

> Return a logger with the specified name or, **if no name is specified, return a logger which is the root logger of the hierarchy**.

Calling the module-level `info()` function [logs directly to the root logger](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#logging.info):

> Logs a message with level INFO **on the root logger**.

If you have no use for specifically named loggers (for example in order to identify the emitting module of the log), the two calls are exactly equivalent.

Comment: If you have `%(module)s` in your log format, then you don't need getLogger to identify the module.